# Inserting data in My SQL using JSP casuing issues: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to inserting the values in the My sql database using JSP bu it causing below issues:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(firstname,lastname,dob,email)values('gerg','egrg','gegre','egeg'))' at line 1

Can you please help? How I can resolve for this simple task? Below is the code:

```
<%
            String firstname = request.getParameter("firstname");
            String lastname = request.getParameter("lastname");
            String dob = request.getParameter("dob");
            String email = request.getParameter("email");
          try{ 
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bookstore", "root",""); 
                Statement st = conn.createStatement();
                st.executeUpdate("insert into users((firstname,lastname,dob,email)values('"+firstname+"','"+lastname+"','"+dob+"','"+email+"'))");
                out.println("Data Inserted in DB");
                st.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                 out.println(e);
            }
            %>
```

Comment: You have two parentheses instead of one at the beginning and at the end of the query. But the main problems are that 1. a JSP shouldn't contain JDBC code. It's a view component, which should just generate HTML. Put that code in a class, called by the controller. 2. You really, really need to learn about prepared statements, because your code will fail if a value contains a quote, and is an open door to SQL injection attacks. 3. a date of birth should be stored as a date, not a string.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet. I was trying to add just dummy value. Your suggestion worked for me.